# Suppose f and g are nonnegative measurable functions from S to $[0,\infty]$ . Show that $\{s \in S \mid f(s)\gt g(s)\}$ is measurable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative measurable functions from $S$ to $[0, \infty]$. Show that $\{s \in S \mid f(s)\gt g(s)\}$ is measurable (wrt the sigma algebra on $S$).

There is an answer here [Let $f,g$ be measurable functions, show that $\{s\in S: f(s) = g(s)\}\in \mathcal{A}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2558359/let-f-g-be-measurable-functions-show-that-s-in-s-fs-gs-in-mathca)

If someone could elaborate on the reasoning in the solution (I have almost no feel for these objects) It would be helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Edit: Also, my professor prefers me to relate to the ray sets $\{s\in S\mid f(s)\leq t\}$ and not arbitrary Borel sets, as is done in the solution posted.

Answer (score 3):

$f(s) >g (s)$ iff there is a rational number $q$ such that $f(s)>q>g(s)$. So we can write $\{s:f(s)>g(s)\}$ as $\cup_{q \in \mathbb Q} (\{s: f(s) \leq q\})^{c} \cap \{s:g(s)<q\}$. To finish the proof note that $\{s:g(s)<q\} =\cup_n \{s:g(s) \leq q-\frac 1 n\}$.